# Order of Operations in android, why are so going on?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a strange problem with the order of execution methods.
A progress bar`.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`appears only after the operation `geocoder.getFromLocation` is end.

summarizing:

- first is 60 sec `geocoder.getFromLocation`
- after the download I see `progressWheel.setVisibility`

my expectations:

**Firstly, I want to see progress , later start time-consuming operations**

```
void doSomethingTimeConsuming()
{
   progressWheel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
   {
       List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
       progressWheel.setProgress(i);
   {
}
```

program must be running on the main thread without thread

Yes, of course I know that I should not do so in the main thread, I ask because I'm curious about why there was such a strange situation, I would like to understand better to avoid such of situations in the future.

Comment: It happens exactly because you do getFromLocation in main(UI) thread.

Comment: here is your problem `program must be running on the main thread without thread`.

Comment: You're freezing your UI. That's why your order of execution is out of whack. Android is single-threaded by default. Have a read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> program must be running on the main thread without thread

Well that's the problem. You're performing an expensive operation (`getFromLocation`) on the UI thread. Don't do that, basically. You're stopping the UI from being updated because the UI thread is busy calling `getFromLocation`.

You *should* use another thread for this operation - marshalling back to the UI thread where appropriate to update the UI.

Comment: How exactly do I know that the operation will block the main thread? Not possible to run everything in a separate thread and queue management. Of course, I can usually identify intuitively or testing, but I hope to get a more precise answer.

Comment: @user3871754: Well the documentation does explicitly say "The returned values may be obtained by means of a network lookup. The results are a best guess and are not guaranteed to be meaningful or correct. It may be useful to call this method from a thread separate from your primary UI thread."

Answer (score 0):

Your UI thread is blocked on this line:

```
geocoder.getFromLocation
```

You should perform it on a different thread(consider execute it using handler).

Comment: That's why I called earlier setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

why not finished  first setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) then the main thread could be blocked?

Comment: Because sometimes things aren't synchronous as they seems. The implementation of setVisiblility() is ambiguous to us and may contain async code. for ex. it may trigger redrawing of the entire view hierarchy or at least measuring and drawing the current view, depends on other conditions. Sometimes you can learn about behaviours like this only from practice.